# Visual Studio 2017 is constantly adding IDC_STATIC to my Resource.h causing compilation warnings

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, mfc, resource-editor

From possibly the first compilation of a project I created from scratch with the File->New->Project dialog, creating a dialog-based MFC application, I've been getting this warning:

```
1>c:\local\proj_vc17\diskovery\triage\resource.h(69): warning C4005: 'IDC_STATIC': macro redefinition
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\atlmfc\include\afxres.h(343): note: see previous definition of 'IDC_STATIC'
```

As an old-hand C/C++ guy from Unix, it's obvious what the problem is, but not why it's happening.  I can't remove this because the Resource Compiler step (I can't figure out how to see the command line doing this--not visible in project->Properties->Resources->Command Line nor visible by selection project->Properties->Resources->Suppress Startup Banner=no) includes `Resource.h` without including `afxres.h`.  So, I add a conditional compilation thusly:

```
#ifndef IDC_STATIC
#define IDC_STATIC                      -1
#endif
```

I wasn't getting this error for several days since the last fix, but I created a new button in the dialog editor I called IDC_HELP.  The resource editor then duly put that in `Resource.h`, where it conflicts with a cursor ID.  I renamed my buttons to IDC_HELPB but the now-unused IDC_HELP was not removed from Resource.h, necessitating a hand edit.  (Note to MSFT: don't allow control IDs that conflict with MSFT-defined symbols.)  OK, so I hate to do this but I don't see an alternative: I hand-edited `Resource.h` to remove the IDC_HELP.  For some reason it then then regenerated `Resource.h`... happily without re-adding IDC_HELP, but again removing the conditional compilation of IDC_STATIC.

I'm not sure enough of the exact problem to know what my question is!  Should I be asking, how to remove an unused (and conflicting) symbol from Resource.h?  Or should I be asking how IDC_STATIC ever got in there in the first place?

Resource.h as it stands.  Only hand-edits are the conditional compilation placed around IDC_STATIC, which MSFT put there, not me.

```
//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated include file.
// Used by Triage.rc
//
#define IDC_MYICON                      2
#define IDD_FOOBAR_DIALOG               102
#define IDS_APP_TITLE                   103
#define IDD_ABOUTBOX                    103
#define IDM_ABOUT                       104
#define IDI_FOOBAR                      107
#define IDI_SMALL                       108
#define IDC_FOOBAR                      109
#define IDR_MAINFRAME                   128
#define IDD_DIALOG1                     129
#define IDD_WINFOOBAR                   129
#define IDD_FOOBAR                      129
#define IDR_WINFOOBAR                   130
#define IDR_FOOBAR                      130
#define IDI_ICON1                       131
#define IDI_DIR                         131
#define IDD_START                       132
#define IDD_PROGRESS                    133
#define IDC_ICHI                        1000
#define IDC_NI                          1001
#define IDC_SAN                         1002
#define IDC_SHI                         1003
#define IDC_GO                          1004
#define IDC_ROKU                        1005
#define IDC_SHOWOK                      1006
#define IDC_NANA                        1007
#define IDC_HACHI                       1008
#define IDC_DIRL                        1009
#define IDC_DIR                         1010
#define IDC_UP                          1011
#define IDC_EXPLORER                    1012
#define IDC_PROPERTIES                  1013
#define IDC_SELSUM                      1014
#define IDC_DIRSUM                      1015
#define IDC_BROWSE                      1017
#define IDC_KU                          1018
#define IDC_GREETING                    1019
#define IDC_ROOTL                       1020
#define IDC_ERROR                       1021
#define IDC_PROGRESS                    1022
#define IDC_ERRORL                      1023
#define IDC_SEP                         1024
#define IDC_BUTTON1                     1025
#define IDC_HELPB                       1027
#define ID_OPEN_                        32771
#define ID_FILE_OPENLISTS               32772
#define ID_FILE_EX                      32773
#define ID_FILE_JUU                     32774
#define ID_FILE_JUUICHI                 32775
#define ID_VIEW_ALLSIZEDATA             32776
#define ID__UNDO                        32777
#define ID__REDO                        32778
#define ID_SAVELISTS                    32779
#define ID_FILE_JUUNI                   32780
#define ID_FILE_JUUSAN                  32781
#define ID_FILE_EXIT                    32782
#define ID_FILE_SAVELISTS               32783
#define ID_UNDO                         32784
#define ID_REDO                         32785
#define ID_OPENLISTS                    32786
#define ID_JUUGO                        32787
#define ID_JUUROKU                      32788
#define ID_EXIT                         32789
#define ID_ALLSIZEDATA                  32790
#ifndef IDC_STATIC
#define IDC_STATIC                      -1
#endif

// Next default values for new objects
// 
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NO_MFC                     1
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        134
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         32791
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         1029
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           110
#endif
#endif
```

Here's the preamble of my RC file.  I note it's somewhat different to a freshly-created New Project-->MFC-->MFC Application-->Dialog Based, but I believe that's how I created this project as well.

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#include "targetver.h"
#endif
#define APSTUDIO_HIDDEN_SYMBOLS
#include "windows.h"
#undef APSTUDIO_HIDDEN_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// English (United States) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Icon
//

// Icon with lowest ID value placed first to ensure application icon
// remains consistent on all systems.
IDI_FOOBAR              ICON                    "Foobar.ico"

IDI_SMALL               ICON                    "small.ico"

IDI_DIR                 ICON                    "dir.ico"


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Accelerator
//

IDC_FOOBAR ACCELERATORS
BEGIN
    "?",            IDM_ABOUT,              ASCII,  ALT
    "/",            IDM_ABOUT,              ASCII,  ALT
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog
//

IDD_ABOUTBOX DIALOGEX 0, 0, 203, 63
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "About Foobar"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    ICON            IDR_MAINFRAME,IDC_STATIC,14,14,21,20
    LTEXT           "Foobar Analyzer, v. 3.2",IDC_STATIC,42,14,154,8,SS_NOPREFIX
    LTEXT           "Copyright (C) 2019.  All rights reserved.",IDC_STATIC,42,26,154,8
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,146,42,50,14,WS_GROUP
END
```

(The file then describes the other dialogs of the app.)

Comment: This would be a *lot* easier to answer if you had shown your resource.h file.  Editing it by hand is risky, it is normally maintained by the resource editor.  That's not a sophisticated piece of software that has a full-blown C parser, it tries to find the place to generate #defines by a simple text search.  I'd guess the IDC_STATIC definition got moved into the wrong place.  Have a look-see at a clean one generated by a new project, the placement of #ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED matters, I think.  What's before it doesn't get messed with.

Comment: `IDC_STATIC` should not be defined in `resource.h`. Please [edit]  your question and add the content of `resource.h`.

Comment: done...........